# Pipe delimited instead of coma through utl_file

Tags: oracle, plsql, pipe, utl-file

Is it possible to generate the .CSV file with pipe (`|`) delimiters instead of comma (`,`) through UTL_FILE package?

Kindly share me how to do if it is possible.

Thanks,
Janardhan.

Answer (score 2):

Sure you can write nearly anything in a csv file ...

```
declare  
   v_file utl_file.file_type;
begin  

   v_file := utl_file.fopen('DATA_FILE_DIR', 'example2.csv', 'W');
   utl_file.put_line(v_file, 'colid|colstring|colnumber|coldate');  
   utl_file.put_line(v_file, '1|"nothing"|231.12|2019-01-03 23:43:32');
   utl_file.put_line(v_file, '2|"not more"|121|2020-10-05 14:33:15');
   utl_file.FFLUSH(v_file);  
   utl_file.fclose(v_file);  
end;
```

Comment: Thanks Thomas for your inputs. But when i open the CSV file, all the data will be available in a single column. Is it possible to separate the data based on the Pipe delimited?

Comment: As written from @APC you have to choose how to open the file. But why did you need to write the file with | when you don't know how to open a csv-file?

Answer (score 2):

> when i open the CSV file, all the data will be available in a single column
>   Is it possible to separate the data based on the Pipe delimited?

That is a feature of MS Excel, regardless of how the file was produced. What you need to do is

1. In MS Excel open a new book
2. From the menu **Data** > **From text**
3. In the Wizard choose **Delimited** option
4. On the next step choose **Other** and put `|` in the box
5. Press **Finish**

Excel will now open your file with multiple columns as defined by the pipes.